# Error while writing excel file using arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

I want to write excel file in java using POI. I want to use object array in arraylist and write in excel.

Please take a look at the code below

```
File f=new File("d:\\nik.txt");
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        String p=null;
        p=br.readLine();
        List<Object[]> lines=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
//      Object[] o=new Object[];
        while (p!=null) {
            System.out.println(p);
            p=br.readLine();
            lines.add((Object)p);//Getting error here
        }
        List<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(lines);
        int rowCount=0;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet();
        for (Object obj : list) {
            Row row=sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            int cellCount=0;
            for (Object o : obj) { //Getting error here
                Cell cell=row.createCell(cellCount++);
                if (o instanceof String) 
                    cell.setCellValue((String) o);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your time reading through the code

Comment: I am getting error during compile-time only. The method add(Object[]) in the type List<Object[]> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: You get this error because of `lines.add((Object)p);` instead of `lines.add((Object[])p);`

Comment: lines.add((Object[])p). This does not work

Comment: `lines.add((Object[])p);` makes the code compileable. I guess [J.H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46131128/6505250) is right, and `lines` must be a list of `Object`s instead of `Object[]`s. Or better, instead of `List<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>();` use `List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();` (and `lines.add(p);` instead of `lines.add((Object)p);`). The  type of `list` (if you really want to have a list for a single element) is then `List<List<String>>` instead of the unspecific type `List<Object>` (which avoids the `instanceof` check).

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Object> lines=new ArrayList<Object>();

        while (p!=null) {
            System.out.println(p);
            p=br.readLine();
            lines.add((Object)p);
        }
```

You are trying to create a list with an Object array in it not just Objects elements.